# boostrap issue in single page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to create a card component for array elements and on clicking the header of the card, a modal should be opened showing the info of that particular array element. However on clicking on the header, multiple modals are opened, in essence even if I click on a header of a particular element, all the array elements modals open up. How do I make it so that only the modal of that particular modal opens up? I'm using vue bootstrap

```
     <div
        v-for="(value,key,index) in flowers"
        :key="value"
        class="card"
      >
        <div v-b-modal.modal-1 class="card-header" >
          <div>
            {{ value.name }}
          </div>
          <b-modal id="modal-1" title="Flowers">
            <p class="my-4" v-for="item in value.petals" :key="item">{{item}}</p>
          </b-modal>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the same `id` to all your modals. Meaning you're creating a bunch of modals with the id `modal-1`, and then clicking the header you're telling your code to open all modals with the id `modal-1`.

You need to give each modal a unique `id`.

In the below snippet I'm using the `key`, but if you have a unique value for each entry, i would suggest you use that instead.

```html
<div
  v-for="(value, key, index) in flowers"
  :key="value"
  class="card"
>
  <div v-b-modal:[`modal-${key}`] class="card-header" >
    <div>
     {{ value.name }}
    </div>
    <b-modal :id="`modal-${key}`" title="Flowers">
      <p class="my-4" v-for="item in value.petals" :key="item">{{item}}</p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one question, suppose there are other buttons on the header and I dont want the modal to open when I click on that other button on the header but if I click anywhere else, then i want the modal to open. how to do that?

Comment: Use the `.stop` modifier on your click event. `<button @click.stop="onClick">`, this will stop the event from propagating up to the header event.

Answer (score 1):

I think all your modals have the same id `id="modal-1"`. You can try to use the `key` of the top `v-for` like an id, something like this `id="modal-{{key}}`.

This is an example:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in items" v-on:click="select($event)" id="{{ item.ID }}">
     <td class="cod">{{ item.ID }}</td><td class="name">{{ item.NAME }}</td><td class="cat">{{ item.CATEGORY }}</td><td class="price">{{ item.PRICE }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: yeah I want to use the key from v-for but not sure where to use it. I tried `v-b-modal.modal-1(key)` and in `<b-modal id="modal-1">` and also your solution but it didn't work for me